# Accidentally put in a Google AdView widget into my app and now it doesn't work even after deleting it

Tags: java, android, admob, adview

So I'm making a game on Android Studio and just for fun I dragged in a Google AdView widget into one of my XML layout files. Even after deleting the widget my app crashes on start with this error.

```
2019-09-08 01:26:53.468 26990-26990/x.x.x.x E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: x.x.x.x, PID: 26990
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************


        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6289)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6204)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1785)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************


        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxi.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:27)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.2.0:3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6742)
            ... 10 more
```

I've searched the app for anywhere that has "ads" or "google" but to no avail. Checked the AndroidManifest and build.gradle too.

Here's the XML of the layout that I dragged the AdView into.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped16"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.923"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.803" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped13"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.082"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.803" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped11"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.646"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.634" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.923"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.467" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped7"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.646"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.467" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.082"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.467" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.373"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.467" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped12"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.923"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.634" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.923"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.646"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.373"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.082"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.373"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.634" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.082"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.634" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped14"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.373"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.803" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#48DB50"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:onClick="tapped15"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.646"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.803" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="147dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.567"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.116" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.073"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do let me know if there's anywhere else to check for some line of code that may be causing this. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried removing the google dependencies from your build.gradle?

Comment: Thank you. It was this line in the build.gradle (Module:app)

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'